# VSCode warning on @use in scss file

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

I have an scss file that looks like this

```
@use "colors";

.content {
    color: colors.$text;
}
```

This compiles fine with my current version of sass (I'm using dart-sass version v1.23.7)

But VSCode shows 3 problems in the problems panel which looks a little like this
[image: Problems in VS Code]

It seems like I need to do something to update the underlying version of scss used but I can't for the life of me work out where this setting is?

The details of one of these errors is:

```
{
    "resource": "Untitled-1",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "css-ruleorselectorexpected",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "at-rule or selector expected",
    "source": "scss",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this extension [scss modules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wongjn.scss-modules) will fix that problem until the new syntax is incorporated into vscode.

Track https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81943

---

Update: v1.41 is adding support for scss modules.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#sass-modules-support

> **Sass Modules support**
>
> Sass recently introduced a new module system.
>
> We have added syntax highlighting support, as well as language feature
>   support for SASS Modules in SCSS files. The language features include:
>
> - Auto completion of @use and @forward
> - Path completion for @use and    @forward path
> - Auto completion of SASS built-in modules such as sass:math and sass:color
> - Document Link for @use and @forward import paths

Comment: Seems Microsoft have added syntax checking so ```@use``` will not show as bad syntax and you even get a help message BUT they have not added the capability to pre-compile ```@use```. I have some VSCode where I get no syntax warnings in the source for ```@import``` or ```@use```, but when I run the precompiler it works with ```@import``` and errors on ```@use```. So read the "SASS Module Support" piece above absolutely literally, they do not say they actually pre-compile the new modules.