# SCSS how do I access style elements in another file

Tags: css, sass

I am new to SCSS and no doubt this is a dumb question. I have a .scss file and I want to access style elements in another .css file and @extend with them.

This works but is not what I want.

```
.w3-table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    width:100%;
    display:table
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#f1f1f1
}

tr{border-bottom:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221)}

.mxa-records {
    @extend .w3-table;
    @extend tr:nth-child(even);
    @extend tr;
    color:red;
}
```

I want to get .w3-table from w3.css, so as I understand it I want to @use w3.css as follows.

```
@use 'w3';

tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#f1f1f1
}

tr{border-bottom:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221)}

.mxa-records {
    @extend w3.w3-table;
    @extend tr:nth-child(even);
    @extend tr;
    color:red;
}
```

From the @use statement w3 becomes my namespace and I somehow should be able to reference .w3-table from within the w3.css file. BUT I get this error.

```
Compilation Error
Error: ".mxa-records" failed to @extend "w3.w3-table".
       The selector "w3.w3-table" was not found.
       Use "@extend w3.w3-table !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 10 of sass/c:\Users\Mark Kortink\Dropbox\Python\projects\PlayPen\sassy\css\mxa.scss
>>     @extend w3.w3-table;
   ------------^
```

I get the same error if I omit the w3 name space.

Am I just deluding myself that SCSS allows me to reuse style elements from other files? I hope not, but how do you do it?

Comment: Can't you just do `@extend .w3-table` since you're using that file at the top?

Comment: You can use @import directive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343131/trying-to-use-sass-modules-in-create-react-app-with-the-new-use-syntax-but-rece)

Comment: @MarioBoss the `@import rule` is no longer recommended by SASS. The `@use rule` is your friend now instead https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: @MikePoole `@use` is only supported by Dart Sass for the moment so using `@import` might be the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, all I have tried all those suggestions and same problem. I use VSCode and it would give a different error if @use was unsupported, but @import doesn't work anyway. I have tried all permutations and combinations including ```@extend .w3-table```. The error message is clear,  .w3-table cannot be found, I assume that means it is at least being looked for and the syntax is legal.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question based on the comments received, thanks @Arkellys and others.

It turns out VSCode does not support the latest changes to SCSS, so you cannot use @use or @forward or other new features with the VSCode SCSS extension. Note that @import is deprecated and will eventually disappear, but still works in VSCode.

There is a better answer to my question that I discovered after reverting to @import and it is here [stackexchange 58974574](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974574/vscode-warning-on-use-in-scss-file) .

BUT note I also discovered another problem in VSCode, the @import statement will not import a .css file, it will only import .scss files. This is contrary to the official SCSS specs.

The @import-based code that worked for me was...

```
@import 'test2';

tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#f1f1f1
}

tr{border-bottom:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221)}

.mxa-records {
    @extend .w3-table;
    @extend tr:nth-child(even);
    @extend tr;
    color: $var;
}
```

with test2.scss

```
$var: brown;

.w3-table {
    background-color: $var;
}
```

This generated...

```
.w3-table, .mxa-records {
  background-color: brown;
}

tr:nth-child(even), .mxa-records {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

tr, .mxa-records {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.mxa-records {
  color: brown;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=mxa.css.map */
```